# bash builtin "read" after a pipe "|" doesn't wait for user input

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, pipe

When I curl a script stored on my web server, it endlessly echos a prompt I coded in until I send ^c. All i do is a simple `curl https://server/test.sh | bash`. This is the code being ran through the pipe

```
while true
do
        read -r -p "[Y/n] " input

        case $input in
            [yY][eE][sS]|[yY])
                        echo "y"
                        break
                        ;;
            [nN][oO]|[nN])
                        echo "n"
                        break
                        ;;
            *)
                echo "y/n"
                ;;
        esac
done
```

Comment: That is, most likely, because `read` recieves `EOF` through the pipe and returns everytime.

Comment: @Raffa and how to i fix this issue?

Comment: Title makes no sense.

Comment: @David You're right ... I changed the title to reflect the actual issue ... I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### In brief

You are probably expecting `read` to behave the same way when it’s run without a pipe and wait for user input … Well it won’t as it’s STDIN is tied to the anonymous pipe and the only normally expected input is what comes through that pipe.

Then, why does it return immediately and repeatedly in the loop when no input is coming anymore through the anonymous pipe and that pipe has actually closed?

This is most likely because `read` receives `EOF` through the closed pipe as its STDIN and returns everytime the while loop iterates ... You can reproduce this with e.g. :

```bash
echo 'while :; do read -r -p "Y/y" i; echo "${i}$(date)"; done' | bash
```

A workaround would be using `bash`'s own [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) syntax i.e. `<(...)` like so:

```bash
bash <(echo 'while :; do read -r -p "Y/y" i; echo "${i}$(date)"; done')
```

Therefore, you can do something like this:

```bash
bash <(curl https://server/test.sh)
```

#### In detail

From [`help read`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-read):

```
Exit Status:
The return code is zero, unless end-of-file is encountered, read times out
(in which case it's greater than 128), a variable assignment error occurs,
or an invalid file descriptor is supplied as the argument to -u.
```

Testing and comparing `EOF` exit status:

Termination with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (*will result in `EOF`*):

```bash
$ read input; echo "Exit code for EOF with Ctrl+D is: $?"
Exit code for EOF with Ctrl+D is: 1
```

Reading empty file (*will result in `EOF`*):

```bash
$ touch emptyfile
$ read input < emptyfile; echo "Exit code for EOF with reading an empty file is: $?"
Exit code for EOF with reading an empty file is: 1
```

Reading from a closed pipe:

```bash
$ echo 'read input; echo "Exit code for EOF when reading from a pipe is: $?"' | bash
Exit code for EOF when reading from a closed pipe is: 1
```

Isolating `bash`'s Exit code after a pipe without `read` (*for reference*):

```bash
$ echo 'echo "Exit code for bash alone after a pipe: $?"' | bash
Exit code for bash alone after a pipe: 0
```