# STDIN redirection issue in ubuntu 20 (works in ubuntu 18)

Tags: 20.04, bash, scripts, c++, redirect

I have a script that runs my application (c++) with STDIN redirected from a fifo and redirects STDOUT to a file.
The following code runs just fine on ubuntu 18:

`./my_app 0</home/user/pipe 1> log.txt &`

I'm sending instructions to the fifo with printf:
`printf "ins\n" > /home/user/pipe`

In the app reading is done `std::getline` in a try-catch block which works just fine on ubuntu 18, but on ubuntu 20 `eofbit` and `failbit` are always set after the first instruction is read.

The whole script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

./my_app 0</home/user/pipe 1> log.txt &
sleep 1
printf "ins1\n" > /home/user/pipe
sleep 5
printf "ins2\n" > /home/user/pipe
.
.
```

For the example above, i am able to read 'ins1' but nothing after

Later edit:
Working now, with something to keep the pipe open.
`sleep infinity > /home/user/pipe &` before starting the app and killing the `sleep` at the end

Comment: You might need to keep the pipe open with e.g. `tail -f /home/user/pipe` in another process ... Pipes are like normal files in that an EOF is reached but when the pipe closes.

Comment: I have already tried to keep it open in the background, the behavior is the same. The thing that bugs me is why the exact same code works on ubuntu 18. Thanks

Comment: I don't know how it might have worked in the past as it shouldn't ... A pipe should close when there is no writer/reader holding it open and then an EOF is seen by the reader ... `</home/user/pipe`  will not keep it open after the writer exits/stops. However something like `tail -f /home/user/pipe` will.

Comment: See for example https://askubuntu.com/a/1463649 and https://askubuntu.com/a/1456567

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that the same program application and script will work on a different version of  Ubuntu (or Linux or UNIX in general).

The [manual page for `fifo`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html) refers to the [manual page for `pipe`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) for the semantics of I/O.

> If all file descriptors referring to the write end of a pipe have
> been closed, then an attempt to `read`(2) from the pipe will see
> end-of-file (`read`(2) will return 0).  If all file descriptors
> referring to the read end of a pipe have been closed, then a
> `write`(2) will cause a `SIGPIPE` signal to be generated for the
> calling process.  If the calling process is ignoring this signal,
> then `write`(2) fails with the error `EPIPE`.

I expect that commands like

```
printf "ins1\n" > /home/user/pipe
```

will open the pipe, write the data and close the pipe, so the receiving program should see an end-of-file condition.

The only way to prevent this is to keep the pipe open for writing. This is what you achieve with the `sleep` command shown in the question.

Comment: Well written ... +1

Comment: I know this shouldn't worked in the first place, but it did. I believe it worked at least on ubuntu 16 18.04.1, because that code hasn't been changed in years. Thanks!